# Controlling the size of legend markers separately from the font size of legend labels

Tags: matlab, plot

I need to control the markers in my legend separately from the font size of the legends' labels. Inspired by [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/348946-how-to-set-legend-marker-size) previous question, I used this code, in Matlab 2016a:

```
x = 1:10;
plot(x, 1*x, 'o')
hold on
plot(x, 2*x, 's')
h_legend = legend({'one','two'});
objhl = findobj(h_legend, 'type', 'line'); % objects of legend of type patch
set(objhl, 'Markersize', 99); % set marker size as desired
```

However, whatever I type in place of the 99, makes no difference. If I change the 'line' into 'patch, that also makes no difference. The problem I guess comes from the fact that objhl is actually empty:

```
>> objhl = findobj(h_legend, 'type', 'patch')
objhl = 
  0x0 empty GraphicsPlaceholder array.
```

Any thoughts? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the difference seems to've been made by whether the result was assigned to the first or the second variable that 'legend' outputs. If the 5th line is replaced by

```
[~, h_legend] = legend({'one','two'});
```

then the result is the expected one.